# How do I create copyable html code with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects called sections. Each object (section in sections) has properities like `name`, `cssclass` and more. Ex:

```
    $scope.sections = [
                     { title 'first section', cssclass: 'red'},
                     { title: 'second section', cssclass: 'blue'}
                     ];
```

What would be the best way to output some HTML-Code in the view that any user can copy?
Let's say for example that it outputs exactly

```
<section class="red"> <h1> first section </h1></section>
<section class="blue"> <h1>second section</h1></section>`
```

and so on for looping for all the objects that the sections array may have.

Just to clarify one more time, I'd like a textarea (or something similar) where the html isn't processed but shown to the user in raw form

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what this has to do with Angular and how the exact structure of your sections-object matters for all of this. I think you could get better help here if you narrowed your question down a bit more

Comment: updated, is it clearer now? excuse my english I'm argentinean !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use 'pass' in $compile to do directive-processing at will and then do whatever you want with with the angularJS-generated HTML. In addition, one has to supply a unique scope based on the user's model input to the new element, which can be accomplished with $rootScope.$new(). In the example below, the model format is expected to be JSON, so that it doesn't like, explode, but if one is creating this for personal use one could allow simple JS input and use eval(), allowing the user to write a more sophisticated model.

Here it is in action: http://jsbin.com/taqoqi/1/

```js
var module = angular.module('module', []);
module.directive('xxAngulizer', function($compile, $rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div>TEMPLATE</div><textarea id="template" ng-model="template" ng-change="update"></textarea>' +
      '<div>MODEL</div><textarea id="model" ng-model="model" ng-change="update"></textarea>' +
      '<div>HTML OUTPUT</div><textarea id="output" ng-model="output"></textarea>' +
    '<div id="hidden" ng-hide="true"></div>',
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, elem) {
      var templateElem = $(elem.find('#template'));
      var modelElem = $(elem.find('#model'));
      var outputElem = $(elem.find('#output'));
      var hiddenElem = $(elem.find('#hidden'));

      $scope.template = '<div ng-repeat="cat in cats">{{cat.name}} the famous {{cat.breed}}</div>';
      $scope.model = '{ "cats": [{ "name": "Fussy", "breed": "Russian Blue" },' +
        ' { "name": "Juniper", "breed": "Maine Coon" },' +
        ' { "name": "Chives", "breed": "Domestic Shorthair" }] }';
      $scope.output = '';
      $scope.update = update;

      var $magicScope;

      function update() {
        var model, template;
        try {
          model = JSON.parse($scope.model);
        } catch (err) {
          model = null;
          $scope.output = 'Model is not valid JSON.';
        }
        if (model) {
          try {
            template = $($scope.template);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            template = null;
            $scope.output = 'Template is not valid(ish) HTML.';
          }
        }
        if (template) {
          if ($magicScope) { $magicScope.$destroy(); }
          $magicScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
          for (var p in model) {
            $magicScope[p] = model[p];
          }
          //$scope.$apply(function() {
            $compile(hiddenElem.html(template))($magicScope);
          //});
          //$scope.$apply(function(){
          //  $scope.output = hiddenElem.html();
          //});
          setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.output = hiddenElem.html();
            $scope.$apply();
          }, 500);
        }
      }

      $scope.$watch('template', update);
      $scope.$watch('model', update);
      setTimeout(update, 500);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="module">
  <div xx-angulizer></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help!